# magento 2.2.6 installation error?

Tags: error, installation, magento2.2.6

[image]

[image]

I have the following issue to installating magento 2.2.6 in local server

Please any one guide me to solve this issue:

Comment: have you checked log and report files?

Comment: It may be occur when you install one magento and that magento's process not complete still you install other magento.

Comment: Try to regenerate process again.

Comment: I will tried and installed magento2.2.6 in local host 2 times still I faced the error

Comment: please the update screenshot after that I have the following error

Comment: error is"An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details."

Comment: enable magento log and if still not getting what exact error then enable php error from `app > bootstrap.php` in add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` remove comment from `#ini_set('display_errors', 1)`

Comment: after I do that it shows the following error "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details."